# Skip validation with Close[X]box of windowsform?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, skip, controlbox

Is it possible to skip validation with Close[X]box of windowsform?
Something like this with a button that skip validation when hit

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
   Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think what you want could be done in your form's [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event.

Comment: How i will do it with formclosing?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16544523/2322994

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    // Intercept WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE
    if (m.Msg == 0x112 && (m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0) == 0xf060) this.AutoValidate =   AutoValidate.Disable;
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: You would rather override WndProc than use the FormClosing event? Why?

Comment: Because it does not work.